# How do I correct this ValueError?

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I have a .csv file that I read into a data frame. I grouped it and added the totals for the columns I need. I then output the data to a csv file. When I look at the data, it looks correct. When I run the program, I get a ValueError.

I have tried a number of things including only creating the columns I need from the original file.

I have also opened the file in Excel and verified that there isn't erroneous data in the column.

```py
with open("Batting.csv", "rb") as Batting:
   csv_batting = csv.reader(Batting)
   csv_batting.next()

    def combine():
      df = panda.read_csv("Batting.csv", index_col=0)
      combo = df.groupby('playerID')
      combo.sum().reset_index().replace(r'\\n', '').to_csv('Combo.csv', column    s=('playerID', 'AB', 'H'), index=False)

combine()

with open("Combo.csv") as csv_combo:
   def average():
     for row in csv_combo:
        try:
           a = float(row[2])
           b = float(row[1])
           return (a / b)
         except ZeroDivisionError:
           return 0

with open("Bat.csv", "w") as Bat:
     csv_avg = csv.writer(Bat)
     for row in csv_combo:
         average()
         avg = average()
         player = row[0]
         csv_avg.writerow([player, avg])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./baseballStats", line 85, in <module>
    average()
  File "./baseballStats", line 67, in average
    a = float(row[2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: r
```

Comment: As the error says, one of your values in `row[2]` is a letter `r`.

Comment: check all the `row[2]` values in `Combo.csv` for a string value `r` other than integer value.

Comment: When I change the except to ValueError and print the line that is causing the problem, it prints every line.

Comment: I figured it out, I forgot to add the csv.reader to open combo.csv. As soon as I did that, the error went away

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I forgot to add the csv.reader to open combo.csv. As soon as I did that, the error went away